# Automatizing the sequence of mounting commands

Tags: mount

When I connect a device (tablet, camera, flash drive, external harddrive) to my laptop with Linux I often type the following sequence of commands.
`$ ls /dev/sd*`
Let's say that my device is /dev/sdc
optional `$ sudo mkdir /media/my_flash`
optional `$ sudo chmod 777 /media/my_flash`
`$ sudo mount /dev/sdc /media/my_flash`

Then I will copy some files and

```
$ sudo umount /dev/sdc
```

This sequence guarantees me that the files are copied and nothing bad will happen.

Could you tell me how to automate this sequence of commands? So I will only plug the device, it will recognize to which directory it should be mounted, then I will make some file transfer and then it will signal me (in some way) I can unplug the device? Is there some settings in Linux OS for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The system component that reacts to the connection of a removable device is [Udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev), as mentioned by [SHW](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11807/automatizing-the-sequence-of-mounting-commands/11809#11809). Even the [udev tutorial](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) can be a little daunting; I'll show you a couple of examples.

There are two steps involved: associating a device file (e.g. `/dev/sdc`) with the hardware device, and mounting the device to access the filesystem. Udev's job is the first step, though you can tell it to run an external command such as `mount`.

For known removable devices, I like to use a dedicated device name under `/dev/removable` (that directory name is a personal convention). The following udev rules (to be placed in `/etc/udev/rules.d/my_removable_disks.rules`) create symbolic links with known names for two disks, both identified by a property of the filesystem on their partition 1:

```
KERNEL=="sd?", PROGRAM=="/sbin/blkid -o value -s UUID %N1", RESULT=="1234-5678", SYMLINK+="removable/foo"
KERNEL=="sd?", PROGRAM=="/sbin/blkid -o value -s LABEL %N1", RESULT=="Joe's disk", SYMLINK+="removable/joe"
```

Older versions of udev may need `/udev/lib/vol_id -u %N1` (for the UUID, `-l` for the label) instead of the `blkid` call. There are more things you can match on, e.g. `ATTRS{vendor}=="Yoyodine", ATTRS{serial}=="XYZZY12345PDQ97"` (instead of `PROGRAM==…, RESULT==…`) to match a device's vendor and serial number.

Then you can use a line like this in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/removable/joe  /media/joe  vfat  noauto,user
```

If you prefer an automatic mount, you can add something like `, RUN="mkdir /media/foo && mount /dev/removable/foo /media/foo"` to the udev line. Don't forget to `umount /media/foo` before unplugging.

Comment: Thanks for great solution. I have LVM on some external drives, so longer sequence of commends (including VG activation etc), now I can even add backup scripts to this :).

Comment: Dear reader - if you want to know about available ATTRS, try this with your device: `udevadm info --name=/dev/DEVICE --attribute-walk`

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by writing a UDEV rules, which will "run" the bash script  ontaining the same bash commands, you mentioned.  Whenever you plug the said devices, UDEV will recognize this, and start behave according to rule.

For rule writing, you can follow  [this](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html)  link.

Comment: Ooh, nice. Didn't know that one yet -- Bookmarking the link and adding it to my repertoire.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Which paragraphs from the [link](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) are relevant to me?

Comment: It looks like the thing I'm looking for. I only have not time to read it all these days. I will study it and paste the right answer into your comment in the time I will understand it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There are several auto-mounting daemons nowadays, as well as the `pmount` command which is specifically meant to let  users mount removable devices under `/media` without requiring `sudo` access.

Both Gnome and KDE have the option to automatically mount removable volumes when they're connected; depending on what distribution you installed this function might even default to 'on'.

In GNOME, the options governing this feature are avalaible under `System -> Preferences -> Removable Media`; I've no recent experience with KDE.

Comment: I'd like to do it independently on Window Management Environement (like KDE, GNOME etc.) (As if X was not started).

Comment: Then you'll have to read that link SHW posted, and read pretty much all of it.